# Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component, while importing a component into the main app the error appears

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNAcy.png)[enter image description here][2][I'm importing a component as WelcomePage in my App.js, however, with only one simple line of Hello I have the error 'Text strings must be rendered within a  component.' Anyone who knows why would be deeply appreciated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHPKD.png)

Comment: could you share your App.js code

Comment: Yea, absolutely! I added it in the description.

Answer (score 0):

In your App.js keep the WelcomePage inside a view

```
export default function App() {
  return (
   <View>
    <WelcomePage />
   </View>
  )
}
```

In your WelcomePage keep the Textinside a view

```
export default function WelcomePage() {
  return (
   <View>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
   </View>
  )
}
```